# Data in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby, postgresql, relationship, sequel

I want to store extra data in a many-to-many relationship, similar to [this Django example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), in [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/association_basics_rdoc.html) and Postgres.

In my example, each person has a place they work, and what hours they work there.  Each person can work different hours at the same place.  For example...

```
Joe works at The Bar Mon, Wed & Fri 9-5pm.
Joe also works at The Bar Saturday noon-midnight.
Joe works at Some Pub Sunday 12-5.
Joe started working at The Bar 2013-12-07
Joe started working at Some Pub 2014-12-23
```

I'm wondering how to set up the tables and models to make this as not awkward as possible.  Currently I have a schema like this.

```
create_table(:people) do
    primary_key :id
    String      :name
end

create_table(:works) do
    primary_key :id
    String      :name
end

create_table(:employments) do
    primary_key :id

    foreign_key :work_id,   :work,   null: false,
    foreign_key :person_id, :people, null: false,

    Date :started
end

create_table(:hours) do
    primary_key :id

    foreign_key :employment_id, :employments, null: false

    String    :dow,    null: false,
    Time      :start,  null: false, only_time: true
    Time      :end,    null: false, only_time: true
end
```

How should I create the model associations to join it all together?  Ideally I would like to be able to say something like...

```
joes_hours_at_some_pub = joe.employment("Some Pub").hours
```

...without having to go through the intermediate join table.

Answer (score 0):

[Sequel's advanced association doc](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/advanced_associations_rdoc.html) has an example of this.  Define an Employment model and use :join_table to create a relationship through it.

```
class Person < Sequel::Model
    one_to_many  :employments,
    many_to_many :works, join_table: :employments

    # This allows joe.employment(work).hours
    def employment(work)
        employments_dataset.where(work_id: work.id)
    end
end

class Work < Sequel::Model
    one_to_many  :employments,
    many_to_many :people, join_table: :employments
end

class Employment < Sequel::Model
    many_to_one  :person
    many_to_one  :work

    one_to_many  :hours
end

class Hours < Sequel::Model
    many_to_one  :practice
end
```